# Get largest int from object inside of array that's under a limit

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, discord.js

I'm currently building a Discord.js bot were I wanna give role rewards depending on what level you reach.

This is my main part of the code to figure out what role to give, which works perfectly when your role rewards only have a 1 level difference (so from 1 to 2), but if I go from level 4 to 5 it doesn't know what to remove and just crashes because `prevLvl` is undefined.

When you reach a certain milestone it needs to give a new role and remove the previous one.

```
memberData.level = 4;

levelUpRoles = [ //These ones get pushed in array by user
    {role: 'id1', level: 1},
    {role: 'id2', level: 2},
    {role: 'id3', level: 5},
    {role: 'id4', level: 20},
    {role: 'id5', level: 10},
]

let newLvl = levelUpRoles.find(object => object.level === memberData.level);
let prevLvl = levelUpRoles.find(object => object.level === memberData.level - 1);

if (newLvl) {
    target.roles.add(newLvl.role).catch(console.error);

    target.roles.remove(prevLvl.role).catch(console.error);
}
```

This is what I've so far been able to come up with:

I changed the `prevLvl` to:

```
let prevLvl = levelUpRoles.filter(object => object.level < memberData.level).sort(function (a, b) {return a.level - b.level}).slice(0,-1).slice(-1);
let newLvl = levelUpRoles.find(object => object.level === memberData.level);
if (newLvl) {
    console.log(newLvl);
    target.roles.add(newLvl.role).catch(console.error);
    console.log(prevLvl);
    if (prevLvl) {
        target.roles.remove(prevLvl.role).catch(console.error);
    }
}
```

It first filters all roles that are under my level, then sorts all roles in order from level, then it removes my current role, then it removes all roles except the highest.

Comment: Is the level meant to be a string, I believe that would cause problems with numbers to strings

Comment: Ah sorry, I don't actually use that object, I use a database but tried to simplify my code a little for this example. In the actual code it's an int.

Comment: Can you tell if me I understood the goal correctly? You want to remove all the other level roles and give the current one?

Comment: Okay so, let's say you go from level 1 to level 2. I want role "id1" to be removed and role "id2" to be added. So basically when you reach a certain milestone it needs to  give a new role and remove the previous one.  

The issue is, when you get to level 5, it tries to remove a role from level 4 when there isnt one there to remove. How can I make it so it removes the previous role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering with the edited part of my post I've finally managed to do it!

```
let prevLvl = levelUpRoles.filter(object => object.level <= memberData.level).sort(function (a, b) {return a.level - b.level}).slice(0,-1).slice(-1);
                    let newLvl = levelUpRoles.find(object => object.level === memberData.level);
                    if (newLvl) {
                        target.roles.add(newLvl.role).catch(console.error);
                        if (prevLvl[0]) {
                            target.roles.remove(prevLvl[0].role).catch(console.error);
                        }
                    }
```

This is what I came up with...
First filter only the roles by level that are smaller or same as my level. Then I sort the array from small to big, then I cut everything except for the second highest which will be my previous reward.

Thanks to everyone that helped and led me in the right direction!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `levelUpRoles` will consistently be in ascending order, you can check for the index of the lowest `level` value above `memberData.level` using the `>` operator.

Then, from that index, find the new level and previous level and do the necessary operations.

```js
levelUpRoles = [
    {role: 'id1', level: '1'},
    {role: 'id2', level: '2'},
    {role: 'id3', level: '5'},
]

let nextIndex = levelUpRoles.findIndex(object => object.level > memberData.level);
if (nextIndex) {
    nextIndex > 0 || nextIndex = levelUpRoles.length; // If there is no next level

    const newLvl = levelUpRoles[nextIndex-1];
    target.roles.add(newLvl.role).catch(console.error);

    if (nextIndex > 1) { // If there exists a previous level
        const prevLvl = levelUpRoles[nextIndex-2];
        target.roles.remove(prevLvl.role).catch(console.error);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code has myriad problems replicated from the OP's. It introduces new errors by not accounting for `findIndex()` returns of 0 (the first index) and -1 (not found).

Comment: @danh return of 0 is accounted for by the line `if (nextIndex)`, return of -1 is accounted for by the next line

Comment: So if `nextIndex`  is 0, nothing happens... is that your intent?  How about `add` and `remove` not defined on Array?  How about adding just the `.role` prop (a string, not an object)?  Maybe change this to a snippet?  It will cause you to make some important fixes.

Comment: @danh Well yes... nothing should happen if it is 0. I'm not sure what you mean by `add` and `remove` not defined on Array? `target.roles` is not an Array instance if that's what you're confused on. Also nothing a snippet could really accomplish here without `target`.